# java.net.SocketException: Resource temporarily unavailable

Tags: java, socketexception, sshd

> Hi,
>   We have two servers running simultaneously in the production environment. Sometimes, server1 throws an exception "java.net.SocketException: Resource temporarily unavailable". Below are the details,

Thanks in advance :)

```
Failed to connect to ssh server [10.0.0.0:22]
    org.apache.sshd.common.RuntimeSshException: Failed to get the session.
    at org.apache.sshd.client.future.DefaultConnectFuture.getSession(DefaultConnectFuture.java:43)
    at com.abc.OurSshClient.getSessionWithTimeOut(OurSshClient.java:328)
    at com.abc.OurSshClient.connect(OurSshClient.java:228)
    at com.abc.spi.ConnectionImpl.connectToServer(ConnectionImpl.java:92)
    at com.abc.spi.ConnectionImpl.<init>(ConnectionImpl.java:84)
    at com.abc.spi.ConnectionFactoryImpl.getInvalidConnections(ConnectionFactoryImpl.java:97)
    at com.abc.resource.pool.ConnectionPoolRegistry.runHeartBeatCheck(ConnectionPoolRegistry.java:303)
    at com.abc.resource.pool.ConnectionPoolRegistry$CheckConnectionThread.run(ConnectionPoolRegistry.java:498)
 Caused by: java.net.SocketException: Resource temporarily unavailable
    at sun.nio.ch.Net.connect0(Native Method)
    at sun.nio.ch.Net.connect(Net.java:484)
    at sun.nio.ch.Net.connect(Net.java:476)
    at sun.nio.ch.UnixAsynchronousSocketChannelImpl.implConnect(UnixAsynchronousSocketChannelImpl.java:326)
    at sun.nio.ch.AsynchronousSocketChannelImpl.connect(AsynchronousSocketChannelImpl.java:209)
    at org.apache.sshd.common.io.nio2.Nio2Connector.connect(Nio2Connector.java:53)
    at org.apache.sshd.SshClient.connect(SshClient.java:298)
    at org.apache.sshd.SshClient.connect(SshClient.java:284)
    at org.apache.sshd.SshClient.connect(SshClient.java:274)
    at com.abc.OurSshClient.getSessionWithTimeOut(OurSshClient.java:317)
    ... 6 more
```

---

```
private ClientSession getSession(int connectionTimeout) throws TimeoutException, IOException {
    ConnectFuture connection;
    boolean hasTimedOut = true;
    try {
        connection = this.client.connect(username, host, port);
        hasTimedOut = !connection.await(connectionTimeout);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        throw new IOException("Failed to connect", e);
    }
    if (hasTimedOut) {
        this.client.stop();
        this.client = null;
        this.clientStarted = false;
        throw new TimeoutException("TimeOut Exception while attempting to connect to [" + host + "]:[" + port + "]");
    }
    return connection.getSession();
}
```

Comment: _Sometimes, server1 throws an exception_. Sometimes when? Your question is not clear

Comment: we have 2 payloads PL-1 and PL-2. Connectivity from PL-2 is OK and there is no problem with it. But, PL-1 cannot connect to the network node. Also, I can able to ping from PL-1 to the node. So there is no network issues but getting above exception.

Comment: The code you show does not match the stack trace.  In the stack trace the exception is thrown by `com.abc.OurSshClient.getSessionWithTimeOut` but your code is for `getSession`.

Comment: Based on other similar questions and the fact that you're using a method that _probably_ sets `O_NONBLOCK`, the error likely means you're leaking sockets and all available sockets are in use or awaiting termination due to protocol timeout.  Monitor the application's port usage with `netstat -nat`.

Comment: @JimGarrison Thanks for your prompt response. The method name is getSessionWithTimeOut but not getSession.. it was my typo when posting the code :(

Answer (score 0):

We just changed the port ranges in eVip configuration file and it is working well now.

Thank you all :)